# Linked an image to a VIewController from Storyboard

Tags: image, ios5, viewcontroller

I'm making an app using storyboard.
If I connect the Red Round Button to another ViewController there's no problem, but if I try to connect an image to another one View Controller it doesn't work.
How can I do?

In the principal View I add an ImageViewController, where I put inside it the image I made. I want the user push this image and goes to another page.

Comment: By connection , you mean a IBOutlet of button or IBAction? or do you mean you are using seque to push new viewController?

Comment: Yes, I mean a push to open a new ViewController

Comment: Pushing one view to another is done by a segue. Take a look here to get the concept: http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-Storyboarding-Tutorial-using-Segues-Scenes-ViewControllers-Navigation

Answer (score 0):

UIImage are not meant to invoke a function when tapped by default so you cannot use seque( push viewController directly) however you can add a UIButton instead of UIImageView and push  ViewController on its tapped and can set your image as Image for UIButton from storyboard so it seems as tapping image is invoking ViewController .
Or you can use tap gesture on UIImageView , however you will need to write more code for it . so if you just want to push a ViewController  on image tapped , use first Method.....

Answer (score 0):

Hope fully you can add uibutton fron IB to the desired place. make background of button to clear colour and specify no label and make it of type custom. Now try to push using storyboard. Hurrey worked. set identifier for that push and enjoy.